Secure HLS AES-128 key URI Using hls.js Player
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:18
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI=https://xxx//xxxxx.com/api/xxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/live?signkey=xxxxxxxxx,IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
#EXTINF:10.000000,
chunk-0.ts
#EXTINF:9.120000,
chunk-1.ts
#EXTINF:13.000000,
chunk-2.ts
#EXTINF:4.960000,
chunk-3.ts
#EXTINF:8.880000,
chunk-4.ts

The key URI is my API endpoint URL.. from the API I will be getting the key.
how to pass header authorization whenever a player requests the key URI.
or is there is any way to secure the Key URI?
I use hls.js player

Not optimal, but you could send a custom m3u8 with a unique key url for each user.
